# Algorithm to go through a SimpleWeightedGraph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, weighted

I have a SimpleWeightedGraph that is not complete and I have to find the minimum path to go through all the vertex. I don't know which algorithm should I use.

Comment: dijkstra's algorithm

Comment: But this one is used to find the minimum path between two vertex, how could I tell it to go through all of them?

Comment: Sounds like you want to find minimal length Hamilton path. It's a hard algorithmic problem (no fast algorithms for the general case).

Comment: @kfx I need a complete graph to apply the Hamilton one.

Comment: No. Having a graph that is not complete simply means that the path *might* not exist. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem

Comment: @kfx I get "null" if I apply it, I should get a path as you can go through all the graph.

Comment: Apply what? You need to show some code to get answers.

Comment: @kfx
`public static List<Vertex> minPath(SimpleWeightedGraph<Vertex, Edge> g){
  return HamiltonianCycle.getApproximateOptimalForCompleteGraph(g);`

Answer (score 1):

This problem is known as the traveling salesperson problem. Usually
undirected graphs are used. The idea is to represent all of the cities that a traveling salesperson must visit as vertices
in the graph, with edges between them representing the distance (or cost) for the salesperson to travel between the
cities. The problem is to determine a route starting in some city that travels to every other city and returns to the start
with the minimum travel cost without repeating cities. Unfortunately, no one has found an algorithm to solve this problem that is not exponential in the number of cities (vertices in the graph.) Interestingly, no one has proved that there isn’t such a solution either. This embodies one of the most important and interesting open questions in computer science.

You can look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Exact_algorithms to choose which algorithm works best for your graph, but just know the complexity will be very high if you have a large number of vertices.

Comment: I just have 8 vertices, I'll try to use one of the algorithms you gave to me.